# Sorting 3 numbers yields strange results (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, numbers

The point of this was to find the smallest number, next smallest number and largest number. Then output them in ascending order. However, when I tried to run this program I was getting a 0, an exponential number and a 3 (the numbers entered were 1, 2, 3 to keep it simple and make sure it worked). I'm not sure where these strange results are coming from, there's no math involved so I am not sure how these are even possible. Also, arrays are not allowed in this exercise. Believe me, I would have much rather done this that way.

```
//local variables
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
int numSmall;
int numMid;
int numLarge;

//Prompt the user for 3 numbers
cout << ("Please enter your first number: ")<<endl;
cin >> num1;
cout << ("Please enter your second number: ")<<endl;
cin >> num2;
cout << ("Please enter your final number: ")<<endl;
cin >> num3;

//compare the 3 numbers to find the order
if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3){
    numLarge = num1;
    if (num2 > num3){
        numMid = num2;
        numSmall = num3;
    }
    else
       numMid = num3;
       numSmall = num2;
}
else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3){
    numLarge = num2;
    if (num1 > num3){
        numMid = num1;
        numSmall = num3;
    }
    else
       numMid = num3;
       numSmall = num1;
}
else{
    numLarge = num3;
    if (num1 > num2){
        numMid = num1;
        numSmall = num2;
    }
}
cout << ("The smallest number is: ") << numSmall << endl;
cout << ("The next smallest number is: ") << numMid << endl;
cout << ("The largest number is: ") << numLarge << endl;


//Pause to read output
system ("pause");

//clear screen to display output
system ("cls");

//Indicate to OS successful termination of program
return 0;
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The if inside the else doesn't have an else so there is one control flow that doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems, solve them and it will work fine. (I checked it)

**Problem 1**

Update your last else block as follows. [you are missing a `else` condition if `num1` is not greater than `num2`]

```
else{
    numLarge = num3;
    if (num1 > num2){
        numMid = num1;
        numSmall = num2;
    }else{
        numMid = num2;
        numSmall = num1;
    }
}
```

**Problem 2**

Put curly-braces in the `else` conditions inside the `if` and `else if` conditions block. So, the final code should look like as follows.

```
if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3){
    numLarge = num1;
    if (num2 > num3){
        numMid = num2;
        numSmall = num3;
    }else{
       numMid = num3;
       numSmall = num2;
    }
}
else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3){
    numLarge = num2;
    if (num1 > num3){
        numMid = num1;
        numSmall = num3;
    }else{
       numMid = num3;
       numSmall = num1;
    }
}
else{
    numLarge = num3;
    if (num1 > num2){
        numMid = num1;
        numSmall = num2;
    }else{
        numMid = num2;
        numSmall = num1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did notice the missing braces after posting the original question. I just forgot to edit it after that. But the final else is what I was still missing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoeBurkhart oh! its fine if your problem is solved! accept an answer if you got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is misleading:

> ```
>    else
>        numMid = num3;
>        numSmall = num2;
> ```

Should probably be:

```
else {
    numMid = num3;
    numSmall = num2;
}
```

Otherwise, the code would be equivalent to this, which I believe is not what you intend to do:

```
else {
    numMid = num3;
}

numSmall = num2;
```

There are also logical pathways through your program in which `numMid` and `numSmall` are left uninitialised. Look at the last `else`.

If an uninitialised `int` is read, **undefined behaviour** occurs, which can lead to all kinds of strange effects.

You should use a higher warning level with your compiler. For example, Visual C++ with `/W4` instantly spots the bugs:

```
stackoverflow.cpp(58) : warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'numMid' used
stackoverflow.cpp(57) : warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'numSmall' used
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot else in the last stage of ifs and will always get wrong results if the largest number is the third one.

Comment: Simple things like this make me feel really silly when that is what the issue was. Thank you for noticing that haha. I looked at this over and over trying to see what I was missing. I thought I included the else there. It's working properly now, thank you!

Comment: @JoeBurkhart don't forget to put curly braces in the `else` conditions. you are missing them in your code. look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code. Thanks to everyone for the help.

```
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
int numSmall;
int numMid;
int numLarge;

cout << ("Please enter three numbers: ")<<endl;
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3){
    numLarge = num1;
    if (num2 > num3){
        numMid = num2;
        numSmall = num3;
    }
    else{
       numMid = num3;
       numSmall = num2;
    }
}
else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3){
    numLarge = num2;
    if (num1 > num3){
        numMid = num1;
        numSmall = num3;
    }
    else{
       numMid = num3;
       numSmall = num1;
    }
}
else{
    numLarge = num3;
    if (num1 > num2){
        numMid = num1;
        numSmall = num2;
    }
    else{
        numMid = num2;
        numSmall = num1;
    }
}
cout << ("The smallest number is: ") << numSmall << endl;
cout << ("The next smallest number is: ") << numMid << endl;
cout << ("The largest number is: ") << numLarge << endl;

system ("pause");
system ("cls");
return 0;
```